# Use selenium with tkinter and pyinstaller noconsole

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver, pyinstaller

I created an app with tkinter, selenium and I compiled it with Pyinstaller. It is a gui app, that starts selenium when you click a button. Then, the button raise a thread with selenium instance. It works good with the compiler.

I had a lot of problems to import some files of selenium with Pyinstaller. I search here, and I could solve my first problem. The code to compile with the app is this.

```
c:\Python33\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe -p C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages -F --icon=icon.ico myapp.py
```

It works fine, but when I put the --noconsole flag, the firefox webbrowser never starts. My log says that the process  has completed.

```
 c:\Python33\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe -p C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages -F --noconsole --icon=icon.ico myapp.py
```